# Insert values in a table if that values not found in the columns of another table

Tags: mysql

Data to be inserted in docdownloadrole table only if values not found in **column: accessto, uploadby** from docdownloadroleall table

Below is the details:

**Table Name: docdownloadroleall**

| accessto | uploadby | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hemel | ashik | 2022-03-10 10:08:29 | 2022-03-10 10:08:29 |
| user1 | user2 | 2022-03-10 10:08:29 | 2022-03-10 10:08:29 |

**Table Name: docdownloadrole**

| deptid | docid | accessto | uploadby | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | user1 | user2 | 2022-03-10 10:08:29 | 2022-03-10 10:08:29 |

**My Query**

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN (docdownloadroleall.accessto != 'user1' AND docdownloadroleall.uploadby != 'user2') THEN 
     INSERT INTO docdownloadrole(deptid, docid, accessto, uploadby, created_at, updated_at)
        VALUES (5, 6, 'hemel', 'ashik', NOW(), NOW()) ELSE '' END)
```

**Since user1 & user2 is found in accessto and uploadby column from docdownloadroleall table, therefore insert query will not execute in docdownloadrole. I want to build this as a dynamic query as well.**

Comment: Provide a sample: CREATE TABLE (textual, code-formatted) for all tables, INSERT INTO with sample data, desired final state with explanations.

Comment: @Akina please see if it helps

Comment: If you're just going to do insert and not "insert if none, update if exist", then `INSERT IGNORE`? But you need to make `accessto, uploadby` as `PRIMARY KEY`/unique constraint first.

Comment: Do you know the difference between SQL code and a table? I won't convert...

Comment: By the way, where did you get the information for `deptid` & `docid`?

Comment: @FanoFN accessto, uploadby can't be primary/unique. deptid & docid will insert from the selected item of the dropdowns.

Comment: If those two can't be unique, does that mean only specific `accessto`, `uploadby` values are not allowed to have duplicates?

Comment: yes they are not allowed to have duplicate values

Comment: Let me confirm that, are you saying that any combination of `accessto` & `uploadby` cannot have duplicates?

Comment: [see this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=70926ce178c883d8282199dba957c012)

Comment: yes, any combination of accessto, uploadby from docdownloadroleall table will not be duplicate

Comment: Then, `PRIMARY KEY(accessto, uploadby)` make sure that there will be no duplicate combination. Is there a particular reason not to use it?

Answer (score 0):

full join two table on their common fields and make your query as follows

```
INSERT INTO docdownloadrole 
            (accessto,
             uploadby,
             created_at,
             updated_at)
SELECT dr.accessto,
       dr.uploadby,
       CURRENT_DATE(),
       CURRENT_DATE()
FROM   docdownloadrole dr
       FULL JOIN docdownloadroleall da
              ON dr.accessto = da.accessto
                 AND dr.uploadby = da.uploadby
WHERE  dr.accessto IS NULL
       AND dr.uploadby IS NULL
```

Comment: comparing and checking will work under docdownloadroleall table and then will insert in docdownloadrole table if not found

Comment: it didn't work. deptid & docid is the selected value from dropdowns.

Comment: list of deptid & docid

Comment: I have changed my answer. where do you get list of deptid & docid? another table, if true then specified its name and its columns. for join.